# usb / virtual com port - is it dead?

Tags: drivers, usb

I have video gimbal that I am attempting to setup.

The device, a Basecam 3 Axis unit, has a micro USB port interface.

When I plug a USB cable from my Debian laptop to the gimbal and run "lsusb" I get no changes.  Additionally dmesg shows nothing.  Yet the board receives power (solid red light, solid green light and a high-pitched "chirp" confirms as much).

If I don't see anything listed in lsusb and dmesg, is it a high probability that there is an issue the board itself?

Comment: Any output in `dmesg` when you plug it in? I would expect that it's a driver issue, but you should still get something about the device when plugged in via `dmesg`.

Comment: you could also try `ioping`

Comment: no... Dmesg shows nothing.  I tested other devices which of course work fine and do produce output on dmesg and lsusb...